# is it possible to include multiple choices of params in postman collection?

Tags: api, parameters, postman

I have an endpoint `{{url}}/objects/color={}`

`objects` are either `green`, or `blue` so myparam should be either `green` or `blue` when sending a request in postman.

I want to choose it from the value field through a dropdown or at least document it somehow in the collection that the user should choose either blue or green or otherwise nothing will be returned.

[image]

is it possible to do that?

Comment: Could you not use the description field next to it or add something to the request documentation?

Comment: I don't think that's how Postman works, you would need to define different requests for each option i.e. each color